# AngularJS4 build on top of ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular

Anyone tried building angularJS on top of ASP.NET core.

Can you help me, I'm a java guy I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you seen the .NET templates for Angular? `dotnet new Angular`? You can find out more about them here: https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/04/20/dotnet-new-angular-single-page-application-setup-and-how-the-template-works/

Comment: I think you nailed it. :D